# Simplest way to download a file with scoped storage in a fire and forget way

Tags: android, download, android-download-manager, scoped-storage

I'm maintaining a legacy app where the user can download files with the `DownloadManager` APIs that worked fine in the past, but since Android 10 the scoped storage was introduced and the app broke and nobody noted that the download feature broke.

Currently I have this trivial code:

```
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);

request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, uri.getLastPathSegment());
DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
try {
    dm.enqueue(request);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} catch(RuntimeException e) {
    FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(e);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Download failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

The problem is that I have just the URL and no meta data about the file. The filename is provided by the `Content-Disposition` HTTP header and therefore not directly visible from the URL, same as the meta type.

Can I continue use that `DownloadManager` or do I really need to use the hard way to use okhttp to get the headers and file content and manage the notifications for the progress and insert the download meta data in the correct content provider for the scoped storage.

An important notice the app has not the external storage permission, because the app does not use the downloaded files at all. The user can press the `DownloadManager`s notification to open the file, the app itself does not care about the file itself.

Comment: `past, but since Android 10 the scoped storage was introduced and the app broke and nobody noted that the download feature broke.` Hard to believe. DownloadManager can still download to all public directories on external storage

Comment: To be honest a backend change caused a bug which forced that the downloads were mostly opened in the browser instead of the App. That is not an important feature of the app anyway. Since downloads work now again as intended we see that the download manager is downloading the file, but when you click on the notification the opening app cannot open the file because of that scoped access. When you use the file manager app you can access the download. That is a bit annoying... This is why I'm checking for new solutions

Comment: `but when you click on the notification the opening app cannot open the file because of that scoped access.` Hard to believe again. The uri that the opening app gets from the DownloadManager notification has nothing to do with scoped access and does work here normally.

Comment: Hard to believe or not: The taps on the notification did not work on my device and I did not debug why it did not work. Google Photos and Acrobat Reader were both unable to open the files which I tried to open by clicking on the notification. I see so many bugs in the last time in so many other apps that I have no nerves to debug their bugs. Fact is that it does not work as I'm expecting it.